# Denied permissions to access the device's location

Tags: flutter, dart, geocoding

```dart
Position? position;
List<Placemark>? placeMarks;

getCurrentLocation() async
  {
    Position newPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, //exact location use high
    );
    position = newPosition; //get longitude and latitude
    placeMarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
        position!.latitude,
        position!.longitude,
    );
    Placemark pMark = placeMarks![0];
    String completeAddress = '${pMark.subThoroughfare} ${pMark.thoroughfare}, '
        '${pMark.subLocality} ${pMark.locality}, ${pMark.subAdministrativeArea}, '
        '${pMark.administrativeArea} ${pMark.postalCode}, ${pMark.country}'; 
    location.text = completeAddress;
  }

child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                          onPressed: (){
                            getCurrentLocation();
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.location_on,
```

I don't have any errors in Android Studio, but when I click the button to get the current location it doesn't show my current location.

My manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.market"> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.market">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> //these the permission. should i run smtg for example flutter run?

Answer (score 0):

You have to also request the location permission from the user. The [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package allows you to use the system dialog to ask for permission:

```dart
if (await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request().isGranted) {
  // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
}
```

If permission was already granted, it won't ask the user again but will return true. It also allows you to check if location is turned on:

```dart
if (await Permission.locationWhenInUse.serviceStatus.isEnabled) {
  // Use location.
}
```

You have to request the `locationWhenInUse` permission before asking for `locationAlways`.

(All examples adapted from the package [README](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler).)